# Place list items in two rows with 50% shift

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

I am trying to place list items in two rows so that items from the bottom row are shifted 50% to the right. The order of the items also matters and should be like on the image below:

[image]

Below is the code I've come up with:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/qVgjGv

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 33.33%;
}
ul > li:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
 <li>
  2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
 <li>
  3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
 <li>
  4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
 <li>
  5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
 <li>
  6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
 </li>
</ul>
<!-- / .timeline-list -->
```

As you can see, the shifted items in the bottom get "cut off" by the column. Any ideas how to fix this, or maybe any other solutions, are appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something that you can solve with a flexboxwrap but the first mistake is going to be assume 33.3% actually you want t o make it 28,57 (take in acount the half element in the begining or end of the row. (100/3,5) .

I'll come back  on this after  im done with something else.

Comment: @FelipeQuirós, thanks! Hope this solution will take into account the order of the items as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid layout instead

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); /* number of rows and space taken*/
  grid-gap: 20px; /* gap between each row and column*/
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* how the grid is going to flow */

}

ul>li:nth-of-type(even) {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
  <li>
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
  <li>
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
  <li>
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
  <li>
    5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
  <li>
    6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam id modi nostrum! Dolor cumque neque porro. Harum qui nobis sapiente nostrum est a quas, quaerat repudiandae minima, sed vel!
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the order of the items is not as per the image.

Comment: Ahh, this doesn't work in Edge. Looked too good to be true :-(

Comment: Ended up with using flex-wrap and order properties to get the result if anybody will come across this.

Comment: This should be 100% compatible with latest version of EDGE https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score -1):

Since CSS grids are not universally accepted, here's a solution using Flexbox which works on all major browsers.
Divide your HTML like this, it'll give you an ordered way of figuring out information.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">1. Lorem ipsum!</div>
        <div class="item">2. Lorem ipsum!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">3. Lorem ipsum!</div>
        <div class="item">4. Lorem ipsum!</div>
        </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="item">5. Lorem ipsum!</div>
        <div class="item">6. Lorem ipsum!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, use flexbox to make columns and for each item inside the column, give it 50% width (50% of its parent) and translate the even child by 100% (means 100% of its width)

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 100%;

    .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        width: 100%;

        .item {
            width: 50%;
            &:nth-child(even) {
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can keep adding more items to each column without any loss in readability this way.

Comment: Sorry, but the idea was to have two rows to draw a line between them. I should have mentioned that. In your example I won't be able to do that.